# How to clear a row with an empty cell in one of its columns, without deleting entire row?

Tags: excel, vba, row, shift

A seemingly simple issue:

I have data in Columns A:E. Column E has some blank cells in some of the rows.

I would like to remove ALL THE ROW that include a blank cell in E. **However, Here's the catch**, there is other data in subsequent columns. if I delete the entire row, this data will be also deleted, which I don't want.

To be more specific, I need to:
(1) Check column E for blank cells
(2) When a blank cell if found, clear the row that has this cell, but only Columns A:E
(3) Shift the data in Columns A:E up

I tried:

```
Range("E2:E100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

But this one only shifts data in column E, not the entire row.

of course, i can use:

```
Range("E2:E100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

But like I said, this will delete data in subsequent columns, which I don't want.

Any tips?

Thanks,

Al

Comment: Won't that algorithm always lead to only empty rows from A to E ? And I believe what you are looking for is Range("Ax:Ey").ClearContents where x is your start row and y your end row. To find x such that it is equivalent to shift+up, just do cell.ToEnd(xlUp).Row where cell is your Range variable you use to loop through your rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can't shift the entire and leave some of the row behind, that is a contradiction. It sounds like you want to do this:

```
Range("A" & row & ":E" & row).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Where row is the row number you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

To remove A:E in "chunks" but preserve you other columns intact a full solution is this

```
Sub PartKill2()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
rng2.Cells(1).Offset(0, -4).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, 5).Delete xlUp
Next
End Sub
```

If you wanted to delete the entire row where E was blank, and columns F:End were blank (but otherwise leave the row as is) then this more complex version can be used

```
Sub PartKill1()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lngCell As Long
Dim lngArea As Long
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For lngArea = rng1.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
For lngCell = rng1.Areas(lngArea).Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
If Application.CountA(Range(rng1.Areas(lngArea).Cells(lngCell).Offset(0, 1), Cells(rng1.Areas(lngArea).Cells(lngCell).Row, Columns.Count))) = 0 Then
rng1.Areas(lngArea).Cells(lngCell).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```